# how to get value when a variable name is passed as a string

Tags: r

i write this code in R

```
paste("a","b","c")
```

which returns the value `"abc"`

Variable `abc` has a value of 5(say) how do i get `"abc"` to give me the value 5 is there any function like `as.value(paste("a","b","c"))` which will give me the answer 5? I am making my doubt sound simple and this is exactly what i want. So please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: [FAQ 7.21](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f)

Answer (score 36):

`paste("a","b","c")` gives `"a b c"` not `"abc"`

Anyway, I think you are looking for `get()`:

```
> abc <- 5
> get("abc")
[1] 5
```

Comment: So how do you do the reverse?
Like something(5) 
"abc"

Answer (score 7):

An addition to Sacha's answer. If you want to assign a value to an object "abc" using `paste()`:

```
assign(paste("a", "b", "c", sep = ""), 5)
```

Comment: You could also use the new `paste0(...)` which is short for `paste(..., sep="")`

Answer (score 6):

This is certainly one of the most-asked questions about the R language, along with its evil twin brother "How do I turn `x='myfunc'` into an executable function?"
In summary,  `get`, `parse`, `eval` , `expression` are all good things to learn about.  The most useful (IMHO) and least-well-known is `do.call` , which takes care of a lot of the string-to-object conversion work for you.

Comment: It might be that, but these things are not apparent when you begin to use R. It's hard to read faq's too, if you're not used to the language they use there (at least for not-native speakers)

Comment: @Largh, that's what "The R-Inferno" is for ~_*

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example to demonstrate eval() and get(eval())

```
a <- 1
b <- 2

var_list <- c('a','b')

for(var in var_list)
{
  print(paste(eval(var),' : ', get(eval(var))))
}
```

This gives:

```
[1] "a  :  1"
[1] "b  :  2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a purrr example to do this for multiple vectors

```
text1 = "Somewhere over the rainbow"
text2 = "All I want for Christmas is you"
text3 = "All too well"
text4 = "Save your tears"
text5 = "Meet me at our spot"

songs = (map(paste0("text", 1:5), get) %>% unlist)
songs
```

This gives

```
[1] "Somewhere over the rainbow"     
[2] "All I want for Christmas is you"
[3] "All too well"                   
[4] "Save your tears"                
[5] "Meet me at our spot"
```