# Access the variable just created

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to get value when a variable name is passed as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429829/how-to-get-value-when-a-variable-name-is-passed-as-a-string)

So I'm using assign() to create a variable

```
nam <- "act01"
assign(nam, read.table(text.txt, sep = ", ", header = T))
```

and I'm trying to append the act01 variable just created into another list

```
acts = list()
acts[[1]] <- nam  # something wrong here, I can't find a way to retrieve the variable
```

Is there any function that allows you to convert the string into a variable in R?

Thanks alot

Comment: [FAQ 7.21](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks a ton, I have been struggling on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too much work; just write

```
list()->acts
acts[[1]]<-read.table(text.txt, sep = ", ", header = T)
```

or better

```
acts<-lapply(text.txts,read.table,sep=', ',header=T)
```

where `text.txts` is a vector of your files, made for instance by `list.files()`.

Comment: Thanks, I will do this one next time.