# how to get a variable's value on R

Tags: r, variables

I have four variables like a.1, a.2, a.3 and a.4. How do I get their values inside a for loop in R?

```
a.1 <- 3
a.2 <-3
a.3 <-4
a.4 <-5
sum <- 0
for (i in 1:4)
{
sum = sum + a.i
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a loop for something like this? Can you describe the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: `sum(unlist(mget(paste0("a.", 1:4))))`, though you probably want to store these variables in a list or vector instead of looping through names of variables stored in your environment.

Comment: @josliber thank you!

Comment: @ananda that's my actual problem. I have multiple matrices and I want to sum them up!

Comment: The `for` loop version would be something like `for (i in 1:4) sum = sum + get(paste0("a.", i))`, but that's not really the approach commonly taken with R. An alternative to @josliber's approach (but related) would be `Reduce`: `Reduce("+", mget(paste0("a.", 1:4)))`.

Comment: Nice, was just typing the Reduce solution -- this will be the way to go if the variables actually contain matrices or vectors instead of single values

Comment: @AnandaMahto and josliber thanks! Reduce("+", mget(paste0("a.", 1:4))) will do what i want to do! thank you so much ^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get value when a variable name is passed as a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429829/how-to-get-value-when-a-variable-name-is-passed-as-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example you gave, if you want to use a `for` loop, you need to make the "i" in your iterator usable. First, you can `paste` the "i" value onto whatever the base of your object name is. Second, you can use `get` to access the value, rather than just see the pasted object as a string.

```
a.1 <- 3; a.2 <- 3; a.3 <- 4; a.4 <- 5
sum <- 0
for (i in 1:4) {
  sum = sum + get(paste0("a.", i))
}
```

However, a more likely way to do this in R would be to use the approach suggested by @josliber:

```
sum(unlist(mget(paste0("a.", 1:4))))
```

Or to use `Reduce`:

```
Reduce("+", mget(paste0("a.", 1:4)))
```

---

The obvious advantage of `Reduce` here is that it would work when you are adding matrices of the same size:

```
b.1 <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
b.2 <- matrix(5:8, 2, 2)
b.3 <- matrix(9:12, 2, 2)
b.4 <- matrix(13:16, 2, 2)

Reduce("+", mget(paste0("b.", 1:4)))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   28   36
# [2,]   32   40
```

The equivalent with your `for` loop would be:

```
sum <- matrix(0, 2, 2)
for (i in 1:4) {
  sum = sum + get(paste0("b.", i))
}
```

However, as @josliber mentioned, if you're going to be doing these kinds of operations, it would be better to store your data in a `list` in the first place.